# Getting part of a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have somthing similar to:

```
 String^  s2="22/12/2012";
```

How I can get the year part in another `String` ? The year part of the previous dummy example is 2012.

I am fine with C# if you can give answer, this is the corresponding code:

```
string  s2="22/12/2012";
```

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact, String.Split, Regex ........

Comment: I dont know why someone did downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

`string theYear = DateTime.Parse(s2).Year.ToString();`

Of course you should check that it is a valid string like this:

```
            DateTime theDate;
            string theYear;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(s2, out theDate))
            {
                theYear = theDate.Year.ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string [] split = Regex.Split(s2, @"/");
string year = split[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

var result = DateTime.Parse(s2, new CultureInfo("en-US")).Year;

Change the culture info if required

OR

```
string[] date = s2.Split('/');

 if (date.Length == 3)
 {
    //date[2]
 }
```